# How to disable mouse cursor on LXDE?

Tags: raspbian, lxde

I am using the Pi as display only device,to show a video feed, so I have no icons and no wallpaper. But the mouse cursor is right there in the middle and when I start the video it gets bigger because of the video resolution. So I wanted to disable it completely.

Any help?

(off-topic)
Setting the wallpaper to a blank screen or reducing that inactivity time where the screens blanks wold be useful too.

Answer (score 12):

The following:

```
sudo apt-get install unclutter
unclutter -display :0 -noevents -grab
```

is known to work perfectly on Raspbian Wheezy.

Comment: Works on Jessie as well. Also works from the window manager's autoload.

Comment: done - test disable wifi, disable bluetooth
done - test pointer hide on current image
done - add disable wifi, disable bluetooth to take 2 doc
done - add pointer hiding setting to take 2 doc

Answer (score 10):

The X server has an option `-nocursor` which would permanently turn off the mouse cursor.

You'd need to edit `/etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc` to add the option to the default X startup.

I looked around for other places to possibly inject the additional option (-nocursor), but nothing else comes to mind that is display manager agnostic (LXDE, KDE, GNOME, AwesomewM, Fluxbox, etc).

Unclutter ([mentioned by @lenik](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/10213/34558)) is also a good solution, although it's often not invoked until a user logs in, which may or may not happen in your case, depending on how you're using the system.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Raspbian Jessie.

Comment: @ThN edit the file here: /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf , see http://darmawan-salihun.blogspot.nl/2013/01/disabling-raspberry-pi-cursor-inside.html

Comment: @Boy Wow... Simply amazing. It worked. Thanks Boy. :)

Comment: You'll probably also need to uncomment the line in lightdm.conf

Comment: Much better than `unclutter`, really

Answer (score 3):

Edit the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` by, for example using nano:

```
# nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

First find the line `xserver-command=X`, you can do this in nano using:

```
ctrl+w xserver-command=X
```

uncomment the line and add:

```
-nocursor
```

So it looks like this:

```
xserver-command=X -nocursor
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does? Does it need `unclutter`? Does it completely disable the mouse pointer?

Comment: @not2qubit This pass the -nocursor option to the X server. See the doc here: https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/Xserver.1.xhtml#heading5 It only disable the *display* of the cursor, so it's still there, but only invisible. I had an issue with this as it would still trigger hover effect on webpages. To workaround this, I added the command `xdotool mousemove 9001 9001` to my startup script. It moves the mouse to the bottom right of the screen. `xdotool` can be installed from the raspbian repositories.

Answer (score 2):

On the latest Raspbian Stitch (`4.9.59-v7+`), using `unclutter` seem the best way with simple options of relevant control. One thing I noticed is that using `-idle 0` is a bad idea, and make the mouse flicker and overload the CPU. However, any number above 1s is good. The best option I found seem to be:

```
unclutter -display :0 -idle 3 -root -noevents
```

If you want this to start automatically, you have two add this line prefixed with an `@` in one of two choices of where to put it:

1. `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` (recommended)
2. `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`

Not sure what's the difference, but the `LXDE-pi` one is working.